# Use typescript only for typing javascript with JSDoc

Tags: typescript, jsdoc, type-declaration

I want to add types to existing JS project (only for IDE syntax highlighting, not for add to library @types/)

So, i have file 'TestComponent.js':

```
export const TestComponent = (props) => {
    return <div>{props.someString}</div>;
};
```

And for types declaration i created 'TestComponent.d.ts':

```
interface TestComponentProps {
    someString: string;
}

export type TestComponent = (props: TestComponentProps) => JSX.Element;
```

And added to TestComponents.js JSDoc type:

```
/** @type {import('./TestComponent').TestComponent} */
export const TestComponent = (props) => {
    return <div>{props.someString}</div>;
};
```

And now VSCode highlights props as object which has someString key.

Is it ok to usage typescript just for this?

I know i can go just with JSDoc, but i dont really like JSDoc syntax.

And maybe any better solutions for this?

Comment: Sounds to me like one of the reasons why VSCode team decided to enable some TS analysis features in JS files ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Its perfectly fine. I'd recommend defining types inside the js files, when you can (interfaces in JSDocs are not really supported). The reason for that is even if its OK to have typesctipt files (which your app will ignore), you don't want too much of them, because it'll be messy as your app grows.

So my advice:
When you can use the JSdocs(typesctipt version of course) in your js files. When you can't or in need of complex types / niche cases, use ts files.